# comparison of Flood-fill and Boundary-fill algorithms

Tags: algorithm

Some sources say that the Boundary-fill algorithm works faster and consumes less memory than the Flood-fill algorithm. I would like to know the reason why this algorithm is better, if it is true.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a tutoring service nor is it a forum for general discussions related to broad topics, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: It would help if you 1) quoted the sources you are referring to 2) described what you are trying to do exactly and 3) showed your code and how you measured its performance and memory demand. Thank you.

Comment: There are many variations of flood and boundary fill algorithms. The best of each are very similar. There's no great difference in performance.